# Setting up smartmontools

Tags: lubuntu, smartctl, smart

I recently built a small server running lubuntu and decided it would be wise to setup smartmontools in order to monitor the drive health. SMART seems to be built into lubuntu in gnome-disks, however, it was not configurable to any degree other than on or off. I proceeded to install hdparm and smartmontools and configured both according to this http://zackreed.me/articles/60-spin-down-idle-hard-disks.

My disk, however, still does not enter standby mode. I checked gnome-disks once more and saw that SMART was running itself once every 10 minutes due to turning smartctl on in terminal.

Does anybody know of any way to fix this so that the disk can enter standby mode?